# How can I assign a different popup menu to every reeview item class?

Tags: dolphin-smalltalk

I have a treeview showing different kinds (classes) of objects.
When I right-click on an object, I'd like to show a popup menu with specific to the object class. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mind, I think to have found a solution.
I create a menù in every class, with the menu > fromString function
and I'll try to assign this menu to the treeview contextMenu property when I click on every object ..